# Why do we use xml language for layouts?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I know that XML is used in android apps to follow MVC architecture. It gives a clarity by separating the UI and the program.

But XML is said to be used to carry data over the network.. (well dats what i have read) then why do we use XML and not any other language like html??

I am new to android so please forgive if I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645468/why-is-xml-used-for-the-creation-of-ui-layouts-in-android

Comment: ohh! nice link thanks :)